# Fokker-Planck equality implies sample path equivalence?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let's say we have two densities $p_t$ and $q_t$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ which have the same time-evolution in the Liouville (Fokker-Planck with no noise terms) sense. That is,

$ \frac{ \partial p_{t}(x) }{\partial t }  =  - \nabla \cdot \left( f_t(x) p_{t}(x) \right) \notag \qquad \text{and} \qquad 
 \frac{ \partial q_{t}(x) }{\partial t }  =  - \nabla \cdot \left( g_t(x) q_{t}(x) \right) \notag$

where $\nabla \cdot$ corresponds to the divergence operator. It is easy to see that although $f_t \neq g_t$ we can have the same evolution which means that the solutions $p_t(x)$ and $q_t(x)$ are the same if the initial conditions $p_0$ (say standard Gaussian) are the same. So far so good.

Note that for $p_t$ and $q_t$, there exists corresponding stochastic processes $X_t$ and $Y_t$, respectively, which follow the deterministic ODEs

$ \frac{d X }{d t }  = f_t(X), \quad X(0) \sim p_0(x) \notag \qquad \text{and} \qquad 
 \frac{d Y }{d t }  = g_t(Y), \quad Y(0) \sim p_0(x) \notag$

see ["Interacting particle solutions of Fokker–Planck
equations through gradient–log–density estimation"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.00702.pdf).

**Question:** Although $f_t \neq g_t$, does the fact the the true density follow the same PDE imply that the two stochastic processes $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are somewhat equivalent? I don't see any sensible reason why that should not be the case but I guess I am assuming some regularities on $f_t$ and $g_t$ to ensure uniqueness of the PDE solutions?

Comment: It's obviously not the case that the densities $p$ and $q$ will be equal for any different choices of $f$ and $g$. So is you question rather, whether, if $f$ and $g$ are different, but $p$ and $q$ agree, we can infer on some similarity between $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is exactly the question.